# How spark optimize reading operation when the data arranged in partition?

Tags: apache-spark

Let's assume the data arrange in partitions like this -

```
data
 |---dt=2022-01-01
 |   |---app=x
 |   |---app=y
           .
           .
           .
 |---dt=2022-01-02
 |   |---app=x
 |   |---app=y
           .
           .
           .
     .
     .
     .
```

If I read with spark the parquets in range of dates, of one app, in this way -

```
where_condition = \
            (col('dt').between(start_date, end_date)) & \
            (col('app') == app_id)

spark.spark_session.read.parquet(self.base_path).where(where_condition)
```

Should it be as fast as reading all the data I want by using a list of full paths for all the directories?

How does Spark optimize that? How does it utilize that data is arranged in partitions when reading?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "How"? Its internals? Generally, you can check the `explain` result of the dataframe for seeing the `partition pruning` effect.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to find, the right term - `partition pruning` @meysam

Comment: Great! So I added an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment (and for future searches) this mechanism is called `Partition Pruning` and is not specified only to the parquet file format. The mechanism backs to the implementation of the connector which can prune the read path by choosing the necessary files/records to scan and avoid a full scan operation.